# React Native Drawer Item I want to set icon right side via

Tags: react-native, react-native-drawer

Please check screenshot
1 - Screenshot of Code
2 - Screenshot of Sidemenu

[image]

[image]

Comment: from where do you import `DrawerItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'space-between',
                  padding: 12,
                  color: 'white',
                  borderBottomWidth: 1,
                  borderBottomColor: '#aaaaaa',
                  backgroundColor:
                    global.currentScreenIndex === item.screenToNavigate
                      ? '#c1c0c0'
                      : '#fff',
                }}
                key={key}
                
                onStartShouldSetResponder={() =>
                  handleClick(key, item.screenToNavigate)
                }>
                {/* <View style={{ marginRight: 5, marginLeft: 10 }}>
          
                    <Icon name={item.navOptionThumb}  size={25} color="#273983" />
                </View> */}
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, color: 'black', marginLeft: 10,}}>
                  {item.navOptionName}
                </Text>
                <View style={{ marginRight:5}}>
                    {/* <Icon name={item.navOptionThumb} size={25} color="#808080" /> */}
                    <Icon name={item.navOptionThumb}  size={20} color="#273983" />
                </View>
              </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this its worked for me (react navigation v6)

```
 <DrawerNavigator.Screen
        name="Home"
        options={{
            drawerIcon: ({color}) => (
                 <Icon name="md-home" color={color}
                   style={{    position: "absolute",right: 10,}}
                 />
            )
        }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use drawerLabel property

```
const SyncIconFunc = {
drawerLabel: config=>
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
<Text style={{color:Colors.bg}}>
  Sync Data
</Text>
<Feather
        onPress={() => alert("bell pressed")}
        style={{ position:'absolute',right: 10}}
        size={24}
        color={Colors.bg}
        name="bell"
      />
</View>
};



<Drawer.Navigator>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Catalogues" component={FolderList}/>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Sync Data" component={SyncData} options={SyncIconFunc}/>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={FolderList}/>
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

[image]